# Dotnet to Dotnet call on Ubuntu failing with SSL connection error

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, ssl

I have two projects that I'm running with dotnet 6 on Ubuntu, one is the UI and the other is the API, when the UI makes a call to the API, it returns an exception that is

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException : The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
```

When I run `dotnet dev-certs https --check` it returns

```
A valid certificate was found: A09013A82738B7690B99C4CDECEA868CBA73CB4D - CN=localhost - Valid from 2022-08-25 20:00:24Z to 2023-08-25 20:00:24Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true
```

I used the respective script for Ubuntu from [this repository](https://github.com/BorisWilhelms/create-dotnet-devcert/tree/main/scripts) and the UI and API both show as https in the browser afterwards. As a means of bypassing the check for ssl, I placed this in the Program.cs for both the UI and API

```
public class CustomHttpMessageHandlerBuilder : HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override HttpMessageHandler PrimaryHandler { get; set; }
    public override IList<DelegatingHandler> AdditionalHandlers => new List<DelegatingHandler>();
    // Our custom builder doesn't care about any of the above.
    public override HttpMessageHandler Build()
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            // Our custom settings
            

            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate {return true;}
        };
    }
}
```

and above it

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder, CustomHttpMessageHandlerBuilder>();
```

I also tried the option

```
ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
```

But none of it has any effect, I'd rather not mess with the code too much but if it's a matter of a few lines in the `Program.cs` that would be a viable alternative but preferably I'd like to figure out why my UI and API projects cannot communicate properly.

Comment: Is it an option to use valid SSL certificates? And are you using `services.AddHttpClient()`? You need to configure the handler there if you are. If you're using a self-signed certificate, I'd advise you to at least validate it in some way in your code.

Comment: I had read about that but I concluded that I'd have to replace/alter all of my instantiations of new `HttpClient` object in the project, is that not the case?

Comment: For development, remove HTTP to HTTPS redirection and only expose port 80 for your backend API. Worry about the certificates when you learn more about that in the future, as then you might know how to acquire trustable certificates and you don't need any hack.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: after integrating with IdentityServer, more *UntrustedRoot* errors showed up. I started over cleaning up previous cert, this time it worked for me, I suspect the previous time I did not run this command `sudo update-ca-certificates`, or it ran unsuccessfully somehow and I didn't notice. Leaving my previous "answer" just in case it helps somebody to rule things out.

**Wrong answer, didn't help**
Had similar error.
Environment: Ubuntu 22.04, dotnet 6.
In my case, I created and trusted cert as indicated in microsoft docs:

- Created developer certificate via `dotnet dev-certs ...`
- Trusted cert as indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-https-certificate-on-linux)
- When client tried to communicate with api via httpclient (from factory), would get "...UntrustedRoot..." exception
- Workaround:
  Added this to the http client factory configuration, in `Program.cs`, client app only:

```cs
...
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(serviceProvider => new HttpClientHandler()  
{  
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator  
})
...
```